# AG-Grid: What are the pitfalls of using suppressAsyncEvents=true

Tags: reactjs, ag-grid

In documentation there is a few information about using suppressAsyncEvents.
The only thing is to use this flag when you have some issues with legacy code, but in my case this flag helps me a lot (Not a legacy code issue).
And there is a warning which strongly recommends to not to use this flag with no description what the pitfalls may be.

Comment: Looking [here](https://github.com/ag-grid/ag-grid/blob/latest/grid-community-modules/core/src/ts/eventService.ts#L159), I'd say they introduced their "async" events to avoid weird lag spikes with synchronous events. Probably similar to how [sync XHR requests](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Synchronous_and_Asynchronous_Requests) should be avoided. You don't show any of your code, so it's hard to help, your question is basically an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378).

Comment: Yeah, looks like it is a real cause. Thank you!